# Django Doesn't Accept Variables in Templates

Tags: python, django

For example this is not working:

```
{% for i in artist_number %}
    <li><a href="#{{ forloop.counter0 }}">{{hash_1.items.forloop.counter0.0}}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
```

but this works:

```
{% for i in artist_number %}
    <li><a href="#{{ forloop.counter0 }}">{{hash_1.items.0.0}}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
```

Why does'nt Django simply put the value of forloop.counter0 to here hash_1.items.X.0

This is just an example. Here is another problem I couldn't solve:

```
list = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
hash_1= {}
#some operations done with these variables.

{% for i in list %}
    <li><a href="#{{ forloop.counter0 }}">{{hash_1.items.i.0}}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: You cannot use the value of a variable to do a lookup in this manner. 

Think about it: how would django differentiate between interpreting `hash_1.items.forloop.counter0.0`  as in `items` is a lookup on `hash_1` but suddenly `forloop` is a variable lookup from a different scope and not literally a key called `forloop`?

Comment: This is one of the several glaring weaknesses that have been in the Django template engine from Day 1. I've never met a "template designer", only programmers forced to do the templating work because the designers simply Don't Get It.

Answer (score 0):

You want either [`{% with %}`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#with) or [`slice`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#slice).

Comment: can you please explain how can I make this work by using {% with %} or slice: {{hash_1.items.forloop.counter0.0}}